# How to use snakemake.script in wrappers?

Tags: snakemake

I've been trying to create portable snakemake wrappers that executes pre-created scripts in the "wrapper.py" script. So far though, all the examples I've found call `shell` from `snakemake.shell` to run functions from the command line. So I thought an equivalent for scripts would be using `script` from `snakemake.script` to execute the scripts. But when I use this in a rule, it throws an error like this:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/robertlink/stack_overflow_dummy_example/.snakemake/scripts/tmpqfzkhuv_.wrapper.py", line 7, in <module>
    script("scripts/foo.py")
TypeError: script() missing 19 required positional arguments: 'basedir', 'input', 'output', 'params', 'wildcards', 'threads', 'resources', 'log', 'config', 'rulename', 'conda_env', 'container_img', 'singularity_args', 'env_modules', 'bench_record', 'jobid', 'bench_iteration', 'cleanup_scripts', and 'shadow_dir'
```

Is there a way to easily retrieve the information required for using `script`? Or am I mistaken that I should even use `script` in this fashion? Here's a dummy example to replicate the message:

Directory structure:

```
.
├── Snakefile
└── wrapper
    └── path
        ├── scripts
        │   ├── bar.py
        │   └── foo.py
        └── wrapper.py
```

Snakefile:

```
rule foobar:
    output:
        "foobar.txt"
    wrapper:
        "file:wrapper/path"
```

wrapper.py

```py
from snakemake.script import script

script("scripts/foo.py")
script("scripts/bar.py")
```

foo.py

```py
with open("foo_intermediate.txt", 'w') as handle:
    handle.write("foo")
```

bar.py

```py
with open("foo_intermediate.txt", 'w') as handle:
    foo = handle.read()
    
foo += 'bar'

with open(snakemake.output) as handle:
    handle.write(foo)
```

command run:

```sh
$ snakemake --cores 3
```

Any insight into this would be wonderful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to write a wrapper to call your scripts - the scripts can **be** the wrapper. Maybe take a look at this wrapper based on an Rscript to get the idea:

https://snakemake-wrappers.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wrappers/tximport.html

Comment: You're absolutely correct. For others looking at this, I just collapsed my scripts into the wrapper.py script and had it run accordingly. Thank you, jafors!